# change ordering of dropdownlist

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu

I need a way to reorder this `DropDownList` so that...

```
ListItem lioak = new ListItem("Oak Pre-finished", "pre-finished oak");
```

...will show first.

```
foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{

    if (r[0].ToString().ToLower() == "oak")
    {
        ListItem lioak = new ListItem("Oak Pre-finished", "pre-finished oak");
        dd1Finish.Items.Add(lioak);
    }
    if (r[0].ToString().ToLower() == "white")
    {
        ListItem lioak = new ListItem("White pre-finished", "white");
        dd2Finish.Items.Add(lioak);
    }
    if (r[1].ToString().ToLower() == "unfinished")
    {
        ListItem lioak = new ListItem("Oak Unfinished", "unfinished");
        dd3Finish.Items.Add(lioak);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: and what happens when row don't have "oak"?

Comment: @phil: not really clear what you want to do, actually. Can you explain  in other way, or with example?

Comment: Any reason why you are storing them in different DropDown controls? Also, you are not checking if an "oak" list item was already...this might cause duplication in the dropdown if you're not careful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the "Oak Pre-finished" item at the start of the list you could try [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ffx2x2y2.aspx) -

```
ListItem lioak = new ListItem("Oak Pre-finished", "pre-finished oak");
dd1Finish.Items.Insert(0,lioak);
```

Comment: thanks! i took a different approach in the end but this was what i wanted.